# How to extract text from the specific bounding box images

Tags: python, opencv, pypdf

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image_path='kyc_sample1.jpg'
plot_flag=True
save_output=True
out_folder='outs'
os.makedirs(out_folder,exist_ok=True)
image=cv2.imread(image_path)
def plot(image,cmap=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    plt.imshow(image,cmap=cmap)
if plot_flag:
    plot(image)

gray_scale=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th1,img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray_scale,150,225,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_bin=~img_bin
if plot_flag:
    plot(img_bin,'gray')
if save_output:
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_folder,f'bin_{image_path}'),img_bin)


line_min_width = 15
kernal_h = np.ones((1,line_min_width), np.uint8)
kernal_v = np.ones((line_min_width,1), np.uint8)
img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_h)
if plot_flag:
    plot(img_bin_h,'gray')
if save_output:
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_folder,f'hor_{image_path}'),img_bin_h)
img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_v)
if plot_flag:
    plot(img_bin_v,'gray')
if save_output:
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_folder,f'ver_{image_path}'),img_bin_v)
img_bin_final = img_bin_h | img_bin_v
if plot_flag:
    plot(img_bin_final, 'gray')
if save_output:
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_folder, f'merge_{image_path}'), img_bin_final)

def imshow_components(labels):
    ### creating a hsv image, with a unique hue value for each label
    label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
    ### making saturation and volume to be 255
    empty_channel = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
    labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, empty_channel, empty_channel])
    ### converting the hsv image to BGR image
    labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0
    ### returning the color image for visualising Connected Componenets
    return labeled_img

def detect_box(image,line_min_width=15):
    gray_scale=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th1,img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray_scale,150,225,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    kernal6h = np.ones((1,line_min_width), np.uint8)
    kernal6v = np.ones((line_min_width,1), np.uint8)
    img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(~img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal6h)
    img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(~img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal6v)
    img_bin_final=img_bin_h|img_bin_v
    final_kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
    img_bin_final=cv2.dilate(img_bin_final,final_kernel,iterations=1)
    ret, labels, stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)
    return stats,labels

image_path='kyc_sample1.jpg'
image=cv2.imread(image_path)
stats,labels=detect_box(image)
cc_out=imshow_components(labels)

for x,y,w,h,area in stats:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)

if plot_flag:
    plot(cc_out)
    plot(image)
if save_output:
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_folder,f'cc_{image_path}'),cc_out)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_folder,f'out_{image_path}'),image)

  Required solution: PAN: 577634563744, Name: Mr William Smith Jons
```

Is there any solution to ocr the text and get the required solution mentioned above from the image. The required solution is to get the text which has the bounding box with their labels. Is there any solution using tesseract to extract text which has bounding box and combine letter has Mr William Smith Jons

[image: kyc_sample1]

[image: out_kyc_sample1]

Comment: Take a look at pytesseract, it's a python ocr library if you want to learn how to use it with cv2 here's an interesting article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-detection-and-extraction-using-opencv-and-ocr/

Comment: try camelot-py. it is basically work on tables only.